# Combine results of apply by column

Tags: r

Say, I have a data frame. In my application, dimensions and column names of this data frame are a priori unknown, but for example:

```
  v1 <- sample(1:100, 5, replace=F)
  v2 <- sample(1:100, 5, replace=F)
  v3 <- sample(1:100, 5, replace=F)

  sample_matrix <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
```

I want to apply a function for each row of sample_df. Function is, in fact, also unknown, except that it returns a vector. As a result of the apply operation, I need to have a data frame with the same number of rows.

If a function returns a vector longer then 1, results of apply are combined as columns, not as rows:

```
  dummy_func1 <- function(x) c(1, 2)
  apply(sample_matrix, 1, dummy_func1)

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
  1  1  1  1  1  1
  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

If I know in advance, that function returns more then 1 argument, it can be dealt with transpose:

```
  data.frame(t(apply(sample_matrix, 1, dummy_func1)))

    X1 X2
  1  1  2
  2  1  2
  3  1  2
  4  1  2
  5  1  2
```

However, if the function returns exactly 1 argument, it does the opposite from what is needed:

```
  dummy_func2 <- function(x) c(1)
  data.frame(t(apply(sample_matrix, 1, dummy_func2))

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Currently, what I do in my project, is transpose conditionally, which is kinda ugly:

```
  res <- data.frame(apply(sample_matrix, 1, dummy_func2))
  if(ncol(res) > 1) res <- t(res)
```

The answers I find mostly suggest to use plyr, but I think I cannot use plyr (or can I?), because in my project neither the data frame nor function are known in advance.

My question is, what is the better way instead of using vanilla apply, to have results always be combined into columns, regardless of return length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `lapply()` so you always get a list of results:

```
sample_matrix<-t(sample_matrix)

dummy_func1 <- function(x) c(1, 2)
a <- lapply(as.data.frame(sample_matrix) ,  dummy_func1)

t(data.frame(a))
       [,1] [,2]
    v1    1    2
    v2    1    2
    v3    1    2

dummy_func2 <- function(x) c(1)
b<- lapply(as.data.frame(sample_matrix),  dummy_func2)

t(data.frame(b))
       [,1]
    v1    1
    v2    1
    v3    1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using lapply is a really good idea. My only concern with it is that too many transposes won't be very efficient if the dataset is large.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much; try for example `big<- data.frame( rnorm(5e6),rnorm(5e6));
system.time(t(big))`

Comment: speaking of transposition, I just noticed that my original answer didn't meet your specs because you wanted a rowwise apply. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: About transposition, you're right - I tested it, and the overhead is minimal. But I don't see why you transpose the original dataset in the edit, t(as.data.frame(lapply(sample_matrix,  dummy_func2))) works correct for me.

Comment: ... and it works, but still not super cute. I will accept your answer unless new evidence appear.